# Entity C# add class which inherits from other

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I have two classes in my Entity project, User and UserProfile, UserProfile inherit from User.

Some part of my code instantiate new User, than I want to add UserProfile to my sql database, which will be expanding my User class.
But I don't know how to write it.

I was trying:

```
Users user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(o => o.UserID == UserId);
if (user != null)
{
    UserProfile userProfile= new UserProfile ();
    userProfile.UserID = user.UserID;
    context.Users.AddObject(userProfile);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return "ok";
}
```

but it's not working.
Writing just pure sql it'd be no problem. But I don't know how to write it properly.
Thanks for help.

Comment: UserProfile inherits User? Doesn't sound so good. Do you mean that UserProfile has a reference to User?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? We cannot help you without that information.

Comment: `return "ok";` looks very ugly. First returning the status lead to "Conditional Complexity" code smell and why returning a string. You can use `enum` instead.

Comment: @usr when it comes to context.SaveChanges, I'm getting                 InnerException = {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Username', table 'DnnDB.dbo.Users'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."} It seems like it's trying to add new User, instead of adding reference to existing one

Comment: @AmiramKorach it's inheritance. In Entity project I've User table ( it's actually dot net nuke user )  and my UserProfile which is inheriting from it. Does it sound bad to implement it this way ?

Comment: @mathk sorry for this string, I won't leave it this way, I just wanted to paste only the code that I've a problem with, nothing more..

Comment: Do you have two tables User and UserProfile? If so, then it is not inheritance. Anyway, such inheritance is utilizing the inheritance mechanism in a wrong way. This should be used like "Dog" inherits "Animal" because dog is an animal with additional info, but UserProfile is not a user. It's an information associated with a user.

Comment: @AmiramKorach My user profile has some additional information like bank account number or address so I was treating it like a specialized user type. Probably changing relation would neutralize this problem. But anyway do You now how to solve this problem ? I wasn't able to find any example how to add an class which is inheriting from base class that is already inside database ?

Comment: You need to write `context.UserProfiles.AddObject(userProfile);`

Comment: @AmiramKorach I cannot refer to context.UserProfiles in my code. When I want to get UserProfiles it's context.Users.OfType<UserProfiles>()     but I don't know how to add one ..

Comment: Don't you have a table named "UserProfile"?

Comment: I've but because it's inheriting from User, I just can't refer to it through context.UserProfiles

Comment: I've tried also context.Users.Attach(userProfile);  but I'm getting error "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."